# Building a react project, if user has already subscribed then it should redirect to homepage but if user sign up then pop up planPage

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've used redux to maintain state if user has already subscribed but on reload, already subscribed users are also redirected to planPage instead of homePage because on reload state sets back to initial null state how should i do it then ?

This is my App.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import DetailPage from "./pages/DetailPage";
import ProfilePage from "./pages/ProfilePage";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { selectUser, login, logout } from "./features/userSlice";
import PlanPage from "./pages/PlanPage";
import { getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth, users } from "./firebase";
import { selectSubscription } from "./features/subscriptionSlice";

function App() {
  const user = useSelector(selectUser); 

  const isSubscribed = useSelector(selectSubscription);

  const dispatch = useDispatch(); //hook to access redux dispatch function
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
      // observe the state change in user's sign in activity
      if (userAuth) {
        //logged in
       
        dispatch(login({ uid: userAuth.uid, email: userAuth.email }));
       
      } else {
        //logged out
        dispatch(logout());
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe; // for cleanup the previous state
  }, [dispatch]);

  console.log(isSubscribed);

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        {!user ? (
          <LoginPage />
        ) : (
          <>
            {!isSubscribed ? (
              <PlanPage />
            ) : (
              <>
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
                  <Route path="detailScreen" element={<DetailPage />} />
                  <Route path="profileScreen" element={<ProfilePage />} />
                  <Route path="planScreen" element={<PlanPage />} />
                </Routes>
              </>
            )}
          </>
        )}
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

planPage.jsx file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import { logout } from "../features/userSlice";
import { AiOutlineCheck } from "react-icons/ai";
import { products, users } from "../firebase";
import { getDocs, setDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import Table from "../components/Table";
//import { BiLoaderAlt } from "react-icons/bi";
import {
  showSubscriptionDetail,
  selectSubscription,
} from "../features/subscriptionSlice";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function PlanPage() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const subscription = useSelector(selectSubscription);
  const [prod, setProducts] = useState([]); //useState() hook, sets initial state to an empty array
  const [selectedPlan, setSelectedPlan] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function unsubscribe() {
      const item = await getDocs(products);

      const productItem = item.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id, //id and data pushed into productItems array
        ...doc.data(),
      }));

      setProducts(productItem);
      setSelectedPlan(productItem[2]);
    }
    unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleClick = () => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(() => {
      dispatch(logout());
    });
  };

  const manageSubscription = () => {
    if (subscription) navigate("/");
    navigate(-1);
  };

  async function setData(data) {
    await setDoc(doc(users, `${auth.currentUser.email}`), {
      productType: data,
      email: auth.currentUser.email,
      subscribed: true,
      activateTime: new Date().toLocaleString(),
      planEndTime: `${
        new Date().getMonth() + 2
      }/${new Date().getDate()}/${new Date().getFullYear()}`,
    });
  }
  const subscribeToPlan = () => {
    if (!auth) return;

    dispatch(showSubscriptionDetail({ subscription: true }));

    setData(selectedPlan?.name);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <header className="border-b border-white/10 bg-[#141414] ">
        <img
          alt=""
          src="https://rb.gy/ulxxee"
          width={150}
          height={90}
          className="cursor-pointer object-contain"
          onClick={manageSubscription}
        />

        <button
          className="text-lg font-medium hover:underline"
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          Sign Out
        </button>
      </header>
      <main className="mx-auto max-w-5xl px-5 pt-28 pb-12 transition-all md:px-10">
        <h1 className="mb-3 text-lg md:text-3xl font-medium">
          Choose the plan that's right for you
        </h1>
        <ul>
          <li className="flex items-center gap-x-2 text-sm md:text-lg">
            <AiOutlineCheck className=" h-5 w-5 md:h-7 md:w-7 text-[#E50914]" />{" "}
            Watch all you want. Ad-free.
          </li>
          <li className="flex items-center gap-x-2 text-sm md:text-lg">
            <AiOutlineCheck className=" h-5 w-5 md:h-7 md:w-7 text-[#E50914]" />{" "}
            Recommendations just for you.
          </li>
          <li className="flex items-center gap-x-2 text-sm md:text-lg">
            <AiOutlineCheck className=" h-5 w-5 md:h-7 md:w-7 text-[#E50914]" />{" "}
            Change or cancel your plan anytime.
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div className="mt-4 flex flex-col space-y-4">
          <div className="flex w-full items-center self-end md:w-3/5">
            {prod.map((product) => (
              <div
                className={`planBox ${
                  selectedPlan?.id === product.id ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-60"
                }`}
                key={product.id}
                onClick={() => setSelectedPlan(product)} //here if i have directly called the stateSetter i.e setSelectedPlan then it is getting called soon after the component mount stage, and keeps on rerender the state and getting stuck into loops. hence ()=> setSelected()
              >
                {product.name}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
          <Table products={prod} selectedPlan={selectedPlan} />
          <button
            disabled={!selectedPlan}
            className={`mx-auto w-11/12 rounded bg-[#E50914] py-4 text-xl shadow hover:bg-[#f6121d] md:w-[420px] `}
            onClick={subscribeToPlan}
          >
            Subscribe
          </button>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

subscriptionSlice.jsx (redux-reducer code)

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const subscriptionSlice = createSlice({
  name: "subscription",
  initialState: {
    subscription: null,
  },

  reducers: {
    showSubscriptionDetail: (state, action) => {
      state.subscription = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { showSubscriptionDetail } = subscriptionSlice.actions;

export const selectSubscription = (state) =>
  state.subscription.subscription?.subscription;

export const subscriptionReducer = subscriptionSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: On window reload, all your JavaScript is refetched and states are reset to their defaults, and that is why it’s happening. One way around it would be storing the state in redux and in parallel storing it into localStorage, and then always load the initial  value in redux from local storage. But a more elegant way to do this is to persist the state of already subscribed user in some flag on user object in backend, so that it always reflects true state of user entity on UI and subscription information is persisted in db for all other browsers/session after user has subscribed.

Comment: I've tried to store the already subscribed user in the backend and retrieved the state in App.jsx but after that subscribe button didn't work in planPage.jsx

Comment: What do you mean by subscribe button didn’t work? If an user is already subscribed, why you are even showing the subscribe button to them

Comment: Also may be you can fetch the subscription state, and update the subscription state , every-time on app load, so that your redux state is initialized with updated values instead of nulls.

Comment: I meant that afterwards subscribe button didn't work for new user , sorry for the incomplete info. Will try the solution suggested by you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this features just by defining a state(issubscribed) in App.js and have access to db. if subscription exist in firebase sent back a data if not it will stay null and you can have the simple logic in your routing.